# primefaces ajaxExceptionHandler not working PF 5.1.17

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

if the users session is expired by session timeout I want to show a dialog that informs about it. On this dialog a button guides to the login page.
I am using primefaces 5.1.17 and with ajaxExceptionHandler this should be possible I think. But it does not work. Here some code:

xthml in the main layout:

```
<h:form id="sessionExpiredDialogForm">
<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException" update="sessionExpiredDialogId" onexception="PF('sessionExpiredDialogVar').show();" />
<p:dialog id="sessionExpiredDialogId" widgetVar="sessionExpiredDialogVar" modal="true" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%;">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['jsftoolkit.errorpage.expired.summary']}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:panelGrid style="width: 100%;" columnClasses="centerAligned">
            <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['jsftoolkit.errorpage.expired.summary.button.ok']}" action="#{logoutController.logout}" ajax="false" style="text-align: center !important;" />
         </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

Added an error page in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/icarchive/views/errorpages/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Added el-resolver `org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver` and `org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory` in faces-config.xml.
After the session is expired the ui does not react anymore without dialog or error message.

Thanks
Oliver